# Why was this flag (about a post containing religious slurs and anti-semitic content) declined by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

I spotted [this gem of an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178310/20774) to the question '[What do the symbols on the mummy's face mean?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161465/what-do-the-symbols-on-the-mummys-face-mean)'

Highlights include;

> *Looks like the heretical language of Enochian (which has zero to do with the FIRST ENOCH of the Bible & the apocryphal book of Enoch) but is named after perhaps this **gnostic elitist bullshit idea of the 2nd Enoch.***
>
> *But yeah anyways looks like enochian to me, which wouldn't be surprising thats the same runic language you see on the Satanic Goat pentragram - which is fact. Which would perfectly fit aligned with Hollywood's obsession w all things occult & kabbalah & considering her character worships Set **it would make sense that the language & message on her body in this film would be represenrative of that sick twisted but still very real belief system.***
>
> ...
>
> *Lastly **I find myself thinking the Rotschilds probably love this film,
>   which is a great reason for me to dislike it** & ponder purer positions.*

In keeping with our "Be Nice" policy ("*Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all.*") I flagged it as

> Contains hate-speech against Kabbalah and low level anti-Semitic
>   content.

And was quite surprised when it was declined by a moderator.

---

**Is it now acceptable to call Kabbalah a "sick and twisted belief system"? Is it acceptable to make coded anti-semitic slurs against the (notably Jewish) Rothschild family?**

**In short, why was my flag declined?**

Comment: The general tone and language in that answer could already be enough for a plain old "rude or abusive" flag to begin with.

Comment: @TARS - Sure, but in the event that OP decided to do it again, I wanted to have a record of the flagged question.

Comment: It's not anti-Semitic to express dislike of some person or group of people who happen to be Jewish. If I say the Nazis were evil, does that make me racist against Germans? (Of course, the answer you link to is certainly a rant and worthy of deletion - indeed, it has now been deleted.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - No, but historically hatred of the Rothschilds (a high profile and wealthy Jewish family) has been considered to be "coded" anti-semitism. Everyone knows what you mean. Like if I said that I hated the *sort of people who like musical theatre*.

Comment: Considered by whom? I've never heard of that. Many people's disdain for the Rothschilds and other super-rich banking families has nothing to do with their religion.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Sure, and if that was the *only* thing he'd said that was troublesome, I'd have probably just edited it out. But apparently he has a deep disdain for the Jewish mysticism associated with Kaballah also. Are you *seriously* trying to tell me that you think that he might just be using them as an example of wealthy bankers?

Comment: The answer criticizes:  1) The Second Book of Enoch, 2) gnosticism, 3) Hollywood, 4) Satanism, 5) Kabbalah, and 6) the Rothschilds.  Numbers 1, 5, and 6 are all explicitly Jewish, and number 2 also originated in out of Jewish tradition.  Numbers 4 and 6 are also standard subjects of antisemitic attacks.

Comment: I will say (as an aficionado of conspiracy theories) that while the inclusion of the Rothschilds in these theories definitely sprang from an anti-Semitic premise, they've become such a fixture that a number of conspiracy theorists with nothing against Jews mention them. That said, I'd give better than even odds of this particular individual having *something* against Jews. ;)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Required reading on the subject of the Rothschilds;  https://www.thejc.com/news/news-features/the-rothschilds-the-banks-and-antisemitism-the-truth-and-the-myths-1.450112

Answer (score -1):

*First things first: **the offending answer has long been deleted**, so this is all pretty academic now.*

---

Regardless of the text of your flag, it was bringing problematic and delete-worthy content to moderators' attention and therefore **should have been marked helpful**. Sorry about that.

From a pedantic point of view, though, your flag seems technically invalid, at least at first glance without further research into the issues involved.

- **"hate-speech against Kabbalah"** - well, the only explicit mention of Kabbalah in the answer was "*Hollywood's obsession w all things occult & kabbalah*". Maybe some of the things being insulted also equate to Kabbalah (the language of Enochian"? the "2nd Enoch"?), but moderators shouldn't need this sort of in-depth knowledge of esoteric topics in order to handle flags.
- **"low level anti-Semitic content"** - again, there's no explicit mention of Jews or other Semitic peoples in the answer. You mention that they express dislike of the Rothschilds, but disliking someone who happens to be Jewish isn't the same as being racist against Jews (any more than, for example, hating the Nazis makes me racist against Germans).

Pedantry aside, of course, **you were right to flag this answer**. I'm not sure why you raised a custom mod flag - "not an answer" would have sent it to the review queue for swifter deletion, and "rude or abusive" is best for truly offensive content - but thanks for bringing it to our attention (even though it ended up being deleted without mod involvement). Sorry again for the [declinature](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193356/87724).

Comment: Arguably they're saying that Kabbalah is "sick and twisted." If they are, *and* they actually understand what Kabbalah (by no means guaranteed), then that would be decent evidence of anti-Semitism.

Comment: It is not academic. If for no other reason than that they're free to continue posting and there's no flag record of their inappropriate content other than a *declined* flag.

Comment: That wasn't the only mention of Kaballah. What do you think "*that sick twisted but still very real belief system*" was referring to?

Comment: But why *has* it been declined? Was that just a misclick or a moment of lacking attention? It's perfectly understandable that such things happen, but it would also be good to know that this is what happened. Or was it declined for any of the "academic" counter-arguments listed herein?

Comment: @TARS - An excellent question. Are these arguments (that the post isn't actually *that* offensive) the reason it was declined?

Comment: @Valorum, It sounds like the argument is "more research was needed, and we shouldn't have to research your flags". Did you explain the flag, or did you just flag and move on?

Comment: @Gnemlock - When someone makes an allegation of anti-semitic content and religious intolerance, you would expect the moderator to perform a quite thorough level of research on their own before declining the flag

Comment: @Valorum, I have no idea how much work goes into moderating, I never flag with the assumption that the moderator will look any further into the matter than I have explicitly stated.

Comment: @Gnemlock - Well, I'd like to think that a flag raised by the site's top user, alleging that a user has used offensive language would merit serious review.

Comment: @Valorum, I would like to think that you do not have any such special treatment, top user or not. That's how *flag abuse* happens. I think your neglecting the fact that these are all *volunteer* moderators, who are *human*. They made a mistake. You clearly didn't make much effort to explain yourself, since you've made no such effort to reinforce that you had, even when queried

Comment: I was curious and asked in meta meta. Early days, but consensus seems to be that you should*go into detail*, and for "thorny" issues, *raise it in meta at the same time*. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305650/to-what-extent-should-a-moderator-investigate-a-flag/305651#305651

Comment: Why are we unable to get a comment from the moderator who actually took the action? It always seems to be you having to "cover someone's tracks"

Comment: @Gnemlock You don't need to be an expert on religion to understand that calling an actively practised faith "sick" and "twisted" is "likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc." Additionally, I am extremely disappointed that no moderator has given a real apology or even seemed to truly grasp what the issue was.

Comment: @Rogue Jedi, you assume Kabbalah is recognised as a practiced religion, or even a religion, in the first place. Personally, it came up once, before, in my previous studies of religion. Apart from that, I've personally never heard of it. I've also never heard of gnostic (assuming a relationship to **a**gnostic) or "Enoch". If I seen a flag that simply said "this is offensive", *I would have to do research* to understand why. I have actually *studied* Judaism, before, albeit 10 or so years ago.

Comment: @gnemlock Surely "sick twisted but still very real belief system." is enough for a moderator to realize something is wrong?

Comment: @RogueJedi, not without *explanation*.

Comment: @Gnemlock They're describing a religion they believe is real as disgusting. I don't see how it isn't a clear violation of policy.

Comment: @RogueJedi, I'm not disputing that, at all. I'm saying that a flag should have clearly explained that, instead of just stating it as a fact. As I said, I wasn't sure, myself, so I went as far as asking on the main meta. In this post, the flagger explains himself, but it appears he didn't, in the flag.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I don't think playing the blame game is particularly helpful here.  I would greatly prefer to treat this as a process and human factors issue.  In that context, the identity of the declining mod is irrelevant.

Comment: @Kevin I don’t see how this has anything to do with the “blame game”, more rather why the moderator who flagged it _himself_ felt it wasn’t worthy. If this was another moderator, it isn’t Rand’s job to clean up after him, if it was Rand, well there’s the answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad: The moderators talk to each other, often in non-public fora.  I would be very surprised (and displeased) if Rand had made this answer up out of whole cloth without first discussing it with the other mod in chat.

Comment: @Kevin I’m aware of what the mods do and don’t do, but that is not the same as a moderator justifying their actions themselves. Rand is not a spokesperson for the other mods, this work is part of their job. It would be as much effort to explain yourself in a web chat as it would to make a post

Comment: @Edlothiad: You're welcome to your opinion, but Rand obviously is acting as a spokesperson here notwithstanding your personal preferences.  I don't care whose name is on the answer, I care about what the mod team is going to *do* about it so that this does not happen again.  So far, it looks like the answer to that is "a whole lot of nothing."  By demanding a *mea culpa* from the mod who declined the flag, you're drawing attention away from that reality, and reducing the likelihood that actual progress is made here.

Comment: @Kevin, You too are welcome to your opinion. I personally feel that by knowing _why_ a flag was declined we can discuss how to come to a community agreement on said topic. This isn't a witch hunt. Neither is the mod necessarily _at fault_ as you seem to insinuate. Rand in this case has shown why it may have been mishandled which in this case doesn't put the moderator at fault, but the flagger for lack of being clear. The question isn't about "How do we move on from this rejected flag", it's "Why was this flag rejected". The best answerer to that, is the flag handler. Plain and simple.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I never insinuated that anyone was at fault.  I did suggest that the whole situation is unfortunate and that something ought to change, but that is not fault.

Comment: @Kevin, now I don't speak Latin but Wikipedia has this to say: "*Mea culpa is a Latin phrase that means "through my fault" and is an acknowledgement of having done wrong.*". This implies someone was at fault. So I mean really you had insinuated that someone was at fault, otherwise what is there to apologise for?

Comment: @Edlothiad: I was suggesting that *you* were demanding an admission of fault.  This discussion is clearly pointless and I won't reply to any further accusations you make against me.